# Define default method on abstract type in Julia

Tags: inheritance, module, julia

How can I provide a default implementation of a method in Julia in a separate module? If the abstract type lives in the same module I have no problem, for example, this works just as I expect:

```
abstract type Foo end

howdy(x::Foo)::Union{String, Nothing} = nothing

struct Bar <: Foo end

function howdy(x::Bar)::Union{String, Nothing}
    "I'm a Bar!"
end

struct Baz <: Foo end

if abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__
    bar = Bar()
    s = howdy(bar)
    if isa(s, String)
        println(s)
    end
    baz = Baz()
    t = howdy(baz)
    if isa(t, String)
        println(t)
    end
end
```

However, once I put the abstract type in its own module, it no longer works:

In `src/qux.jl`, I put:

```
module qux

abstract type Foo end

howdy(x::Foo)::Union{String, Nothing} = nothing

export Foo, howdy
end # module
```

and then in `reproduce.jl` I put:

```
using qux

struct Bar <: Foo end

function howdy(x::Bar)::Union{String, Nothing}
    "I'm a Bar!"
end

struct Baz <: Foo end

if abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__
    bar = Bar()
    s = howdy(bar)
    if isa(s, String)
        println(s)
    end
    baz = Baz()
    t = howdy(baz)
    if isa(t, String)
        println(t)
    end
end
```

Then I get:

```
julia --project=. reproduce.jl
I'm a Bar!
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching howdy(::Baz)
Closest candidates are:
  howdy(::Bar) at ~/qux/reproduce.jl:5
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ ~/qux/reproduce.jl:18
in expression starting at ~/qux/reproduce.jl:11
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#using-and-import-with-specific-identifiers,-and-adding-methods) in the Julia manual.

The issue is that in your code, as you can see here:

```
julia> module qux

       abstract type Foo end

       howdy(x::Foo)::Union{String, Nothing} = nothing

       export Foo, howdy
       end # module
Main.qux

julia> using .qux

julia> struct Bar <: Foo end

julia> function howdy(x::Bar)::Union{String, Nothing}
           "I'm a Bar!"
       end
howdy (generic function with 1 method)

julia> methods(howdy)
# 1 method for generic function "howdy":
[1] howdy(x::Bar) in Main at REPL[4]:1

julia> methods(qux.howdy)
# 1 method for generic function "howdy":
[1] howdy(x::Foo) in Main.qux at REPL[1]:5
```

You have two distinct `howdy` functions each having one method. One is deifned in `qux` module, and the other in the `Main` module.

What you want to do is to add a method to `howdy` function defined in `qux` module. I would typically do it by qualifying the exported function name with module name, as this is a clear way to signal what you want to do:

```
julia> module qux

       abstract type Foo end

       howdy(x::Foo)::Union{String, Nothing} = nothing

       export Foo, howdy
       end # module
Main.qux

julia> using .qux

julia> struct Bar <: Foo end

julia> function qux.howdy(x::Bar)::Union{String, Nothing}
           "I'm a Bar!"
       end

julia> methods(qux)
# 0 methods:

julia> methods(howdy)
# 2 methods for generic function "howdy":
[1] howdy(x::Bar) in Main at REPL[4]:1
[2] howdy(x::Foo) in Main.qux at REPL[1]:5
```

as you can see now you have a single `howdy` function having two methods and all will work as you want.